# Phase relationship between polarization density and electric field

Tags: electromagnetism

There is below relationship in linear polar material (frequency domain)

$$P(\omega)=\epsilon_0 \chi(\omega) E(\omega)= \epsilon_0[\epsilon_r(\omega)-1] E(\omega)$$

where $P$ is the polarization density, $E$ is the electric field, $\chi$ is the electric susceptibility, $\epsilon_r$ is the dielectric constant, and $\epsilon_0$ is the permittivity in vacuum.

What is $E(\omega)$? Is it external electromagnetic field or internal field?
As I know $E$ is not external field but total field in matter (external field + field made by polarization).

If this is true I'm really confused when susceptibility has a complex value. Then the polarization density lags behind total field. But I think it is nonsense that the polarization density lags behind the field made by polarization itself. Am I  misinterpreting the concept or making some mistake?

Comment: Doesn't the phase relationship depend on the sign of the imaginary part of $\chi$?

Comment: I'm not sure it's nonsense for the polarization density to lag behind the field made by polarization itself. This is what happens with any oscillation; in springs the inertia lags behind the spring's displacement, which makes the force to move it in the first place, and the system oscillates.